# Junit Implement Execution condition for programatically disabling a test function

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to build a custom annotation to be used along with JUnit test classes. The objective is to periodically run tests.

Example class to run: `TempTest.java`:

```
  @Periodic(period = 2)
  public class TempTest {
    @Test
    @ExtendWith(PeriodicEnabling.class)
    public void testTrue() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    @ExtendWith(PeriodicEnabling.class)
    public void testZero() {
        int val = 0; assertEquals(0, val);
    }

    @Test
    @ExtendWith(PeriodicEnabling.class)
    public void testZero2() {
        assertEquals(0, "".length());
    }

    @Test
    @ExtendWith(PeriodicEnabling.class)
    public void testFalse() {
        assertTrue(!false);
    }
 }
```

So with `period = 2` we want to only run every other (or every 2nd) test. The custom annotation looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(PeriodicEnabling.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Periodic {
    int period() default 1;
}
```

And finally the `PeriodicEnabling` helper class:

```
public class PeriodicEnabling implements ExecutionCondition {
    private int period, currCount;

    private static final ConditionEvaluationResult ENABLED = ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Count looks good!");
    private static final ConditionEvaluationResult DISABLED = ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("Disabled due to periodic disabling!");

    public PeriodicEnabling() {
        System.out.println("Constructor!!");

        Class<TempTest> cls = TempTest.class;

        if(cls.isAnnotationPresent(Periodic.class)) {
            Annotation annotation = cls.getAnnotation(Periodic.class);
            this.period = ((Periodic) annotation).period();
        } else {
            this.period = 1;
        }

        currCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        System.out.println("before::currCount = " + currCount);

        currCount++;

        int result = this.currCount % this.period;

        if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("after::enabled::currCount = " + currCount);
            return ENABLED;
        }

        System.out.println("after::disabled::currCount = " + currCount + ", result=" + result);
        return DISABLED;
    }

}
```

---

### Problem:

The problem is after the first test function's `evaluateExecutionCondition` returns `EvaluationCondition.Disabled`, the rest of the functions do not execute the `evaluateExecutionCondition` function again for them. The rest of the test cases do not run at all.

Here's the output I see when I run the example test file:

```
Constructor!! 

before::currCount = 0
after::disabled::currCount = 1, result=1

Disabled due to periodic disabling!

Disabled due to periodic disabling!

Disabled due to periodic disabling!

Disabled due to periodic disabling!
```

---

I saw some solution where the solution was to use the `assumeThat` function with some dynamic condition within it. But I need something different, I need a custom annotation class to handle the execution of every test function in the annotated class.

Any help is appreciated :) !

Comment: I would recommend looking into JUint RunListener to handle whether or not a test method / Class should be executed and  BlockJUnit4ClassRunner so you can apply the listener to the class under test. There might be other ways, but I think this is a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're applying the extension to the class, so it is not only active for the individual methods, but also the class itself. Jupiter then dutifully calls `evaluateExecutionCondition` to determine whether the class is disabled. Since it is, the individual methods are also disabled without further calls.

There are some other improvements to be made in your code (e.g. you should not have fields in extensions) - I recommend to read read up on the [JUnit 5 extension model](https://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-extension-model/) (link to a post on my blog).

Comment: Thank you so much @Nicolai !! I have followed your blog post as part of my research for the problem. I tried to follow your approach to i.e. using callbacks (beforeEachCallBack and afterEachCallback) - but i found that the value of “count” variable that I stored in the “ExtensionContext.Store” got freshly initialized for each method. Can’t we share a common piece of data in the Store among all test methods and decide whether or not to execute or skip that method based on that value?

Comment: To store something that you need across methods, don't put it into the store of the test method's context. Instead ask for its parent (which is the test class' context) and use that store.